how to put uppercase text into a variable
with this code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images


\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\TeIII}{  tit  e3   }
    \newcommand{\AeIII}{\UseName{author24} }
        \newcommand{\ARTeIII}{TITLE ARTICLE III  
        Article 3 article 3 Article 3 article 3 Article 3 article 3 .Article 3 article 3 Article 3 article 3 }
     \def\tmp#1.#2\tmp{#1}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\MeIII\expandafter{\expandafter\tmp\ARTeIII\tmp}
\TeIII
\ARTeIII

\MeIII
\end{document}

I can extract and then display the value of variable ARTeIII and MeIII
I would valorize also the variable TeIII that is composed of the capital text of the vaiable ARTeIII. I mean as minimum 2 or 3 capital letter consecutive. (not the other cpaital letter following full stop.)
Renato

I can not guess what your intended input is or what your intended output is.  what is \author24 ? please add to your example another non-wroking call and add a comment saying what output you want.

Autor24 is the content of variable AeIII but it doesn't matter for the job I need. I would have the content of  variable TeIII where I have the value "tit e3" with the value "TITLE ARTICLE III. Do it exist a way like I do (someone suggest me) to put a content in MeII that is the character until first full stop?

sorry I can not understand at all your issue, you need to edit the question with a clearer example. You already show the use of a command, \tmp that expands to all characters up to a full stop, but I can not guess where you want to use that.

I don't want to use \tmp. I would (if it is possible) put the capital letter of \ARTIII in TeIII variable

as I say you should edit the question to show what input you want to type and what result you need. If you mean extract TITLE ARTICLE III why that, why not TITLE ARTICLE III A as the following character is also uppercase, classic tex has no easy way to do this you could grab each word up to a space character and test if it is equal to it's uppercase and loop, but it is a lot of work, what is the actual use case? It really does not help that your example code has code that is unrelated (author24) and weird indentation, and has no example at all of what you are actually wanting to do.

I've understood, yes it's a big work. but...
If the first capital letter after the space is on a new line It is just the capital letter of a sentence.
So my title end where I still have more than one capita letternearest

I've understood, yes it's a big work. but...
If the first capital letter after the space is on a new line It is just the capital letter of a sentence.
So my title end where I still have more than one capital letter nearest each other.I mean not less than two capital letter near. maybe this is the trick. not less that two capital letter
Can I translate it in LaTeX?

there is no newline in the definition, it is saved as a space, but it was really only a guess that you wanted that and I can not guess what you mean  by " So my title end where I still have more than one capital letter nearest each other.I mean not less than two capital letter near. maybe this is the trick. not less that two capital letter"   You still have not edited the question, you need to make an example that is much more clear. It seems like an X-Y question really, why do you need to do this, why is there no structure in the input?

As far as I can tell you want something like this that loops over a token list grabbing each word up to the next space and then seeing if it is uppercase. It would be much better to fix the input to have a clear marker, but...
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\aaaaa{TITLE ARTICLE III Article 3 article 3 Article 3}

\makeatletter
\def\grabword#1 {%
  \global\let\gtmpa\relax
  \MakeUppercase{\gdef\gtmpa{#1}}%
  \gdef\gtmpb{#1}%
  \ifx\gtmpa\gtmpb
    \ifx\thistitle\@empty
      \global\let\thistitle\gtmpb
     \else
       \g@addto@macro\thistitle{ #1}%
     \fi
    \expandafter\grabword
  \else
    \expandafter
    \breaktitle
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\def\breaktitle#1\relax{}

\def\findtitle#1{%
  \gdef\thistitle{}%
  \expandafter\grabword#1 xxx \relax}
  
\begin{document}

\findtitle\aaaaa

\thistitle

\end{document}


Produces


yes David is this!maybe I have to perfect it!But I have something to work on! (It's really code I don't know at all...)

@RenatoP really you should arrange that you do not need to do do this. How come you are getting input where the only indication of a title is that it is in uppercase?

@DavidCarlisle You have a very powerful crystal ball!
